# right property not working with position relative

Tags: html, css

The question is that even though the right property is set to 0, then why the child div is aligned to the left side, when it should be on the right side of its parent div?

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.child {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="child">This div element has position: relative;<div>
</div>
```

The result of above code is:

[image]

Comment: Only when div.abs is `position:absolute` it'll stick to the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, I know. But in this case, when position is relative, why it is aligned to left when right is 0?

Comment: because you never delcared `position: absolute;`. The element you want to position absolute also has a `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`

Comment: The question is that what effect ``position: relative`` has on right property. Why it is not working properly with relative.

Comment: again, because you never declared `position: absolute` - relative is only for the parent so that an absolute positioned element know to which element to place absolute at.

Comment: I have updated my question. Now there is no mention of absolute.

Comment: doesnt change the facts stated in the comments. `position: relative` does not place an element differently. It is just a "marker" so that position: absolute has an "anchor" to position at. Without it, the nearest `non-static` parent will be used (which then would be the body).

Comment: So it means right property doesn't work well with position: relative, right?

Comment: it doesn't work at all...

Comment: But it has been mentioned on the tuts that to get right, left or any such property to work, you have to set position first. Then why is it so that right doesn't work with it?

Comment: read above or read the manual... -> [position property MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: PS: the top property doesnt work either. Use `postion: absolute` on the child element and see for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer to my question. My misunderstanding was that when we set `position: relative`, it is set relative to the nearest ancestor, which is not the case. It is set according to where it should be normally. so right property works on its normal position. It does not consider where the nearest ancestor of the element is.